# Selecting Distinct Data from all columns but 1

Tags: mysql, database

I'm using select distinct in order to return only data that is different but I want it to base the distinction on all columns without including the agg_source_tag_tag_name in the distinction.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT agg_article_title,agg_article_link,agg_article_media,agg_article_description,agg_article_source_name, agg_source_tag_tag_name, agg_source_url
FROM agg_article join agg_source ON agg_article_source_name = agg_source_name join agg_source_tag ON agg_source_name = agg_source_tag_source_name 
WHERE agg_source_included = 1
```

I'm getting the following result:

```
agg_article_title | agg_article_link | agg_article_media | agg_article_description | agg_article_source_name | agg_source_tag_tag_name | agg_source_url |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
some title 1      | some link 1      | some media 1      | some description 1      | some source name 1      | tag1                    | someurl1       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
some title 1      | some link 1      | some media 1      | some description 1      | some source name 1      | tag2                    | someurl1       |
```

I get the following returned because all the columns are in fact distinct because of agg_source_tag_tag_name, however, I only want one row back because I want to omit agg_source_tag_tag_name from the distinction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this WITH GROUP BY

```
  SELECT agg_article_title,agg_article_link,agg_article_media,agg_article_description,agg_article_source_name, agg_source_tag_tag_name, agg_source_url
  FROM agg_article 
  join agg_source 
  ON agg_article_source_name = agg_source_name 
  join agg_source_tag 
  ON agg_source_name = agg_source_tag_source_name 
  WHERE agg_source_included = 1 
  GROUP BY agg_article_title, agg_article_link
```

you can group by what ever cloumn you want.